# How do i print elements in ArrayList<String [ ][ ]> in java

Tags: java

Below is my code:

```
public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String args[]){

    String[][] a = {
        {"type"},
        {"emergency"},
        {"manual"},
        {"brand"},
        {"accessGroup"},
        {"memberRef"}             
    };

    String[][] b = {
            {"ab"},
            {"cd"},
            {"ef"},
            {"gh"},
            {"ij"},
            {"kl"}             
        };

    ArrayList<String[][]> al = new ArrayList<String[][]>();
    al.add(a);
    al.add(b);
    Iterator<String[][]> itr = al.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(itr.next()); //prints: [[Ljava.lang.String;@2a139a55
    }
    }
 }
```

The problem here is that the 2D array is inside an `ArrayList`, and I am not sure on how to use 2 for loops to scan through each elements and print it. Could anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked up how to print a 2D array?

Comment: Yes, you run through each element using 2 for loops. But in this case the 2D array is inside an ArrayList. So i am not sure how to go about (or if it is possible at all using Iterator?)

Comment: you can assume that a list of 2D arrays can be treated like a 3D array as a whole

Comment: Why are you making your a and b 2d arrays? As per their content they may be simple 1d arrays.

Comment: @HarishHarry `itr.next()` returns a 2D array. The fact that the arrays are stored inside an arraylist is irrelevant.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: But when i do itr.next(), it prints something like : [[Ljava.lang.String;@2a139a55

Comment: @HarishHarry That's the string representation for the 2D array. It's just a 2D array.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: So how do i print the values within this 2D array?

Comment: @HarishHarry You just said above that you know how to print a 2D array.

Comment: @HarishHarry `next` returns a 2D array. Just save that to a variable and print it out. Again, the fact that the arrays are stored in an array list, and the fact that you're accessing them via an iterator changes nothing.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: Got it, thanks! I am still a noob, apologies for asking silly questions

Comment: @HarishHarry Np. Just don't over complicate things for yourself. Programming is already difficult enough.